# Developer and admin GUI tools for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Сould anybody give advice on any GUI tools for development and administration hadoop?

Answer (score 4):

About an Hadoop UI for the user:

[Hue](http://gethue.com) is pretty good for sending Hive, Impala queries and Pig scripts. It also comes with  some improved File/Job/HBase/ZooKeeper/Sqoop Browsers and an Oozie UI for submitting and scheduling jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Administration

- [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/products-services/tools/) is an administration system for Hadoop and is free in some situations
- [Ambari](http://incubator.apache.org/ambari/) is an open source management system for Hadoop

Development

- [Karmasphere](https://karmasphere.com/what-is-karmasphere) is more than just a development platform now, but it is quite feature packed
- Most people I know [develop Hadoop locally in Eclipse](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment)

Answer (score 0):

Toad Freewares For Cloud databases may also help [Toad Link](http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/default.aspx)
But we need to interact with all Hive, Hbase etc., in SQL